# IBM Mobilefirst Pugin doesn it support Cordova version >7

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, cordova-plugins

Planning to migrate to **cordova version 7.1.0.**
But as i can see in your **cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore,cordova-plugin-mfp,cordova-plugin-mfp-push** according to the **package.json** you support only Cordova version between **">=6.1.1 <7"** but in the **plugin.xml** it says **">=6.1.1 <8"** and in the latest version it says **">=6.1.1 <9"**.

So is it really compatible with the Cordova version i am planning to switch or do you need me to stay in 6 Series ?

We are using

```
"cordova-plugin-mfp": "8.0.2018031007",
"cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore": "8.0.2018021611",
"cordova-plugin-mfp-push": "8.0.2018030609"
```

Getting the Following error

```
[windows] Failed to restore plugin "cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: Failed to fetch plugin cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore@8.0.2018021611 via registry.
[windows] Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.
[windows] Check your connection and plugin name/version/URL.
[windows] Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
[windows] npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
[windows] npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Jenkins\\tools\\jenkins.plugins.nodejs.tools.NodeJSInstallation\\nodejs6\\node.exe" "C:\\ws\\test\\FINGERTIP\\FingertipClient\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore@8.0.2018021611" "--production" "--no-save"
[windows] npm ERR! node v8.11.1
[windows] npm ERR! npm  v2.15.12
[windows] npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID
[windows] 
[windows] npm ERR! peerinvalid The package ajv@4.11.8 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
[windows] npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer ajv-keywords@2.1.1 wants ajv@^5.0.0
[windows] 
[windows] npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
[windows] npm ERR!     C:\ws\test\FINGERTIP\FingertipClient\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: what are your mfp plugin versions in use ?

Comment: These plugin levels should work fine with cordova 7.1.0 .If you would like to use cordova 8.0.0 and cordova-android 7.0.0 then your plugin levels  should be on  levels mentioned in iFix 8.0.0.0-MFPF-IF201804051553  here https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2018/05/18/8-0-master-ifix-release/#changes-in-this-ifix-9

Comment: @manjunathkallannavar i am getting the above error when building android project not sure what to do but IOS works fine in mac.

Comment: Give me your cordova android version and steps to reproduce I will try to on my machine

Comment: no it works fine in our local machine it has problem when doing it in the Windows Server 2012. And it also works fine doing things manually but when doing via Cordova prepare this throws the above error.

Comment: Also for this, it is possible that your project's config.cml has the versions of the MFP plugins hardcoded. Hence on "cordova prepare", you see this error. Please clear these hard coded versions in your config.xml, remove MFP plugins and re-add the latest versions of the MFP plugins to resolve the errors you see.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the latest cordova-plugin-mfp to avail support for cordova 7.x cli. For this while adding the plugin use the command `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-mfp@latest`

Comment: we have updated our Jenkins to the cordova version 7..0 and when build cordova projects using cordova prepare android( specified the cordova things in the package.json) During this cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore errors the version we are using is cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore@8.0.2018021611

Comment: The support for cordova 7 and above have been introduced in the mid of this year. The plugins and their versions that you have mentioned 
"cordova-plugin-mfp": "8.0.2018031007",
"cordova-plugin-mfp-jsonstore": "8.0.2018021611",
"cordova-plugin-mfp-push": "8.0.2018030609"
do not support cordova 7 and above. Hence, please remove the plugins and add the latest plugins to resolve the errors you see.